# How to derive the top contributing factors in a binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, decision-tree, feature-selection

I have a binary classification problem with about 30 features and an ultimate pass/fail label. I first trained a classifier to be able to predict if new instances will pass or fail but now I want to get a deeper understanding.

How can I derive some analysis about why these items pass or fail based on their features? I would ideally like to be able to show the top contributing factors with a weight associated with each one. Complicating this is that my features are not necessarily statistically independent of each other. What sorts of methods should I look into, what keywords will point me in the right direction?

**Some initial thoughts:** Use a decision tree classifier (ID3 or CART) and look at the top of the tree for top factors. I am not sure how robust this approach would be and it isn't immediately clear to me how one can assign the importance of each factor (one would just get an ordered list).

Comment: Hello @adrix, which library are you using to develop the model?

Comment: I can work in anything python or R: scikit-learn, MLLib, pytorch etc. I've been working initially in scikit-learn though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your objectives correctly, you might want to consider a [Random Forest model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest). Random forests have the advantage of naturally providing an importance to the features by virtue of how the algorithm works.

In Python's scikit-learn, check out `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()`. `feature_importances_` would return the "weights" I believe you're looking for. Check out the example in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

Alternatively, you can use R's [randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package. After constructing the model, you can use `importance()` to extract the feature importance values.